# how to connect to a wifi (wpa/wpa2) in ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, wpa2, wpa

I just isntalle ubuntu server 14.04.2, in the installation process i could easily choose the network name from a list and typed the password. After the installation i saw that Im not connected to the internet. It would be great if you tell me how to connect to the internet (noob version please :) ).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via system start using the /etc/network/interfaces configuration.

From terminal,

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

To setup dynamic addresses:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

To setup static addresses:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
```

Input your credentials:

```
wpa-ssid <network>
wpa-psk <password>
```

For static addresses you can supply:

```
address <address>
netmask <netmask>
gateway <gateway>
dns-nameservers <nameserver1>, <nameserver2>
```

Final result:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8
wpa-ssid NETGEAR
wpa-psk password
```

Comment: Netmask is incorrect and also no DNS nameservers listed as required.

Comment: Fixed to your liking.. ;)